# C# + UserControl + Panel is cleared after calls an event

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, webforms

This question involves ASP.NET WebForms. I'm adding a UserControl into a  `asp:Panel` element after selecting an item on some `asp:DropDownList`.

```
protected void dropdownlist_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panelDinamicallyContent.Controls.Clear();
    switch (selectedValue) {

        case 1:
            panelDinamicallyContent.Controls.Add(
                panelContainerControls.FindControl("UserControl1"));
            break;
    }
}
```

Ok, it's working great. When I click on submit button, I call an event. In this event, I do some validations. When I got any error, I'm displaying an alert into the page. Well, after displaying this alert, my UserControl previously added into `panelDinamicallyContent` is removed, dissapeared or something else.

```
protected void buttonSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string validationResult = DoValidation(value1, value2);
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationResult))
    {
        // Do something...
    }
    else
    {
        // show alert...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Controls that are dynamically added to your page have to be added again on each postback. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317515/en-us

Comment: How do you do that if the button which calls the postback is on the usercontrol? For me the click event handler isn't called (breakpoint doesn't get hit) but the panel is cleared :(

Comment: Do you add the usercontrol on each postback?